# how to use jquery for changing my input type="image" width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my original code is

```
<input type="image" src="http://myImage.png?rxc=1491827389" style="width:357px;height:60px;" name="submit" alt="hi">
```

I cant change it directly but I can add CSS/JQuery code, I just want to change the width to 200px so the code will be

```
<input type="image" src="http://myimage.png?rxc=1491827389" style="width:200px;height:60px;" name="submit" alt="hi">
```

I tried different CSS commands and even JQuery but none worked maybe I made a mistake?

Comment: I've edited your answer so your code is in code blocks - but please update them so the HTML is actually correct. Also, you say you've tried CSS/JQuery - please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Satpal: my bad, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can change image width by jquery.Refer my code below,in my code on button click I have changed the width of image

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#abc").css("width","20px");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js">
</script>

  <input id="abc" type="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_submit.gif" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" >
<button>change width</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

give the image an id and access it with

```
document.getElementById("imageid").style.width="300";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name="submit"]").width(200).height(60);
});
```

This is a way for jQuery.

You could also try to use instead of `input[name="submit"]` this:

`input[type="image"]`

Answer (score 0):

Hello I tried like this and it works:

```
<input type="image" src="http://myImage.png?rxc=1491827389" style="width:357px;height:60px;" name="submit" alt="hi">

$('input').css('width','200');
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you try like this?

```
input type="image" src="http://myimage.png?rxc=1491827389" name="submit" alt="hi" width="200" height="60"
```

Comment: OP says he can't edit the element directly, and can only use CSS/JQuery.